# Looping collection to find minimum

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

HI,

I have a collection of strings 
eg
 "test (9)"
 "test (7)"
 "test (5)"
 "test (3)"

I want to loop use a foreach loop to iterate and find the lowest number I have a regex to extract the number out of each string... I need to loop through all items (which are in the format as in my example above) and find the lowest number...?

```
foreach (SPListItem item in items)

{

string item = (String)item["Title"];

string itemNumberString = Regex.Match(UniqueCounteryparty, @"\d+").Value;


}
```

Comment: Have you considered using class to store number separately or is it impossible in your scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm initializing the variable "test" below using array initialization syntax for demo purposes since I'm assuming you have a collection already populated with the strings you need.

> ```
>   string[] tests = new string[] { "test(1)", "test(2)", "test(3)" };
>   int minimum = int.MaxValue;
>
>   foreach(string test in tests)
>   {
>     int num = ExtractNumber(test);
>     if (num < minimum)
>       minimum = num;
>   }
>
>   //now you have minimum that hold the minimum;
> ```

"ExtractNumber" is your function that extracts the number from the string

Comment: That's slightly faster than @Jakub's answer because it avoids unnecessary assignments. I also find it easier to understand.

Comment: @ssg, yes, that was the point on both counts. I like the use of Math.Min but unless one is familiar with that function it's not as readable. And seeing the OP's question I thought it best to keep it simple.

Comment: @ssg - I'm doing *one* assignment per item - Shiv is doing *at least* one per item. I wouldn't judge the performance since you don't know what optimizations the compiler will come up with. The best way is to test it.

Comment: @Jakub, I agree that the best way is to test. I still think Shiv's code is more expressive though.

Answer (score 5):

```
int minValue = int.MaxValue;

foreach(string s in strings)
    minValue = Math.Min(minValue, ExtractNumberMethod(s));
```

Comment: if the strings are ("test 10", "test 8", "test 11) it will say result in test 11 being the lowest when in fact it is test 8 in the collection

Comment: @nav - Your extract number method may return not what you expect - debug it.

Comment: @nav - why do you think my code will return 11 as the lowest number out of {10, 8, 11}?

Comment: As i read the line if code it compare the min value on each iteration of the for loop, so: It doesn't take into account the number before it...

Comment: @nav - Math.Min guarantees you always get the minimum of current and previous minimum value. It's the implementation of minimum function.

Comment: @Jakub thanks! i didn't know that Math.Min remembers its previous value

Comment: @van - No, Math.Min *doesn't* remember previous value - that's why I store it in minValue variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rely on the base class library methods :

- [`Array.Sort<T>(T[])` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/kwx6zbd4.aspx)
- [`List<T>.Sort()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx)

A sample to illustrate the two methods :

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        private static void Method2(string[] strings)
        {
            int[] ints = new int[strings.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
            {
                ints[i] = Extract(strings[i]);
            }

            Array.Sort<int>(ints);

            foreach (int i in ints)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The smallest is {0}", ints[0]);
        }

        private static void Method1(string[] strings)
        {
            List<int> result = new List<int>();
            foreach (string s in strings)
            {
                int value = Extract(s);
                result.Add(value);
            }
            result.Sort();

            foreach (int i in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The smallest is {0}", result[0]);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] strings  = new string[6];

            strings[0] = "test (9)";
            strings[1] = "test (4)";
            strings[2] = "test (7)";
            strings[3] = "test (1)";
            strings[4] = "test (2)";
            strings[5] = "test (8)";

            Console.WriteLine("\nMethod1 :");
            Method1(strings);

            Console.WriteLine("\nMethod2 :");

            Method2(strings);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int Extract(string s)
        {
            // simply extract the digits
            return Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(s, @"\d+").Value);
        }
    }
}
```